# Miracle in decimal.ToString()

Tags: c#, .net

How is this possible?

```
decimal d = ePhrase.MaxPrice; //ePhrase.MaxPrice==3 - Entity (edmx) object from sql 2012 express data field is decimal (18,2)
string t = d.ToString(); //Why does t=="3,00"?
d = (decimal)3.00;
t = d.ToString(); //t=="3"
```

The problem is that in one case t=="3,00", and the other case t=="3"? what difference between these two case?

Thanks to all:

```
decimal d = ePhrase.MaxPrice;
  string t = d.ToString();//t=="3.00"
  d  = 4.0000m;
  t = d.ToString();//t=="4.0000"
```

The problem is "d=(decimal)3.00" -apparently this is not REAL decimal

Comment: Please explain what and why do you expect

Comment: you should use `d = 3.00M;`

Comment: I expect string t = d.ToString();//t=="3", because I'm not using IFormatProvider

Comment: What's the localization settings?

Comment: The problem is that in one case t=="3,00", and the other case t=="3"? what difference between these two case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want a numeric real literal to be treated as `decimal`, use the suffix `m` or `M`

```
d = 3.00m;
t = d.ToString(); //t=="3"
```

Here:

```
d = (decimal)3.00;
```

will not treat it as `decimal` but it will be treated as `double`

**NOTE:** *The `"m"` tells the compiler to treat the `3.00` as a decimal and an implicit cast will happen to originalValue as part of the conversion.*

Refer this for more info: [Decimal in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)